# I Want to display just the name of day without the Date when i put a random Date in java

Tags: java

```
package assignment1;

import java.text.ParseException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SimpleDateFormat SDformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        System.out.println("Enter Date (Month/Day/Year) :");
        String dinput = input.nextLine();
        Date date1 = null;
       
        if (dinput != null && dinput.trim().length() > 0)
            date1 = SDformat.parse(dinput);
       
        System.out.println(date1);
    }  
}
```

the code it makes the user to put any random date , and it will give the day only without time or date just the day like (Thursday) like this only

input : 07/13/2021
Output :
Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 EEST 2021

I want to display just the day like Tuesday .

Comment: As you know how to use a date formatter, can you think of how you might use one to print the day?

Comment: Please state your problem, what your code does, what it should. Give clear input and expected output examples.

Comment: the code it makes the user to put any random date , and it will give the day only without time or date just the day like (Thursday) like this only

Comment: @YazanYousef then put it nicely edited in your question, most of people will not read your comnments.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Under the linked original question there are many answers using java.time. I recommend that you skip the first three answers using old and problematic classes like `SimpleDateFormat` or `Calendar`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What did your search turn up? Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here and when you post a question, tell us what your search brought up and specify how it fell short of solving your problem. It’s for your own sake since (1) you often find a better answer faster that way (2) it allows us to give preciser and more focused answers. It also tends to prevent or at least reduce the number of downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some class that really just takes a date, which `java.util.Date` does not (it is simply a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch).

Here's a small example that **does not validate the input due to brevity**:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // define a formatter for parsing input of the expected pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
    // fire up a prompt
    System.out.println("Enter Date (MM/dd/yyyy):");
    // store the line typed in by the user
    String dinput = input.nextLine();
    // parse it
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dinput, dtf);
    // and print some sentence as result
    System.out.println(String.format("The date %s was a %s", 
            localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE),
            localDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE,
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH)));
    // or an alternative (this time just the day of week, but in a different way)
    System.out.println(localDate.format(
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE",
                                                            Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

Entering `11/11/1988`, for example, would print this:

```
Enter Date (MM/dd/yyyy):
11/11/1988
The date 1988-11-11 was a Friday
Friday
```

Comment: @YazanYousef No problem, you're welcome...